# Kohana 3 ORM - group by case

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-db

I would like to achieve this query with the ORM query builder:

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
GROUP BY CASE `products`.`configurable` 
WHEN 'yes' THEN `products`.`id_configuration` 
ELSE `products`.`id` 
END
```

I know that this works:

```
$products = DB::query(Database::SELECT, '
    SELECT * FROM `products`
    GROUP BY CASE `products`.`configurable` 
    WHEN 'yes' THEN `products`.`id_configuration` 
    ELSE `products`.`id` 
    END
')->execute();
```

But it returns a mysql db result, and I would rather have an ORM list, otherwise I will have to instanciate all my ORM objects in a loop, resulting in poor performance... or...?

Is it possible? The ORM 'group_by' function looks very limited...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define what kind of DB result you want:

```
$products = DB::query(Database::SELECT, '
    SELECT * FROM `products`
    GROUP BY CASE `products`.`configurable` 
    WHEN 'yes' THEN `products`.`id_configuration` 
    ELSE `products`.`id` 
    END
')
->as_object('Model_Product') // !!
->execute();
```

Or, if you use it inside model, you can call `->as_object(get_class($this))` or `->as_object($this)`.

Comment: Brilliant. You just made my day :)